# WPF Update Binding when Bound directly to DataContext w/ Converter

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext, propertychanged

Normally when you want a databound control to 'update,' you use the "PropertyChanged" event to signal to the interface that the data has changed behind the scenes.

For instance, you could have a textblock that is bound to the datacontext with a property "DisplayText"

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayText}"/>`

From here, if the DataContext raises the PropertyChanged event with PropertyName "DisplayText," then this textblock's text should update (assuming you didn't change the Mode of the binding).

However, I have a more complicated binding that uses many properties off of the datacontext to determine the final look and feel of the control. To accomplish this, I bind directly to the datacontext and use a converter.  In this case I am working with an image source.

`<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>`

As you can see, I use a {Binding} with no path to bind directly to the datacontext, and I use an ImageConverter to select the image I'm looking for. But now I have no way (that I know of) to tell that binding to update.  I tried raising the propertychanged event with "." as the propertyname, which did not work.

Is this possible? Do I have to wrap up the converting logic into a property that the binding can attach to, or is there a way to tell the binding to refresh (without explicitly refreshing the binding)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!
-Adam

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The workaround here was to add a property to my object (to be used as the datacontext) called "Self"  , which simply returned

`public Object Self { get { return this; }}`

Then in the binding I used this property:

`<Image Source="{Binding Path=Self, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>`

Then when I call

`PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Self"))`

it works like a charm.

Thanks all.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was mad looking for this and was about to ask it when it appeared on my suggestions

Comment: @Adam, what an awesomely elegant hack! Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way of accomplishing exactly what you need with your current converter.  As you mentioned, you could do the calculation in your ViewModel, or you could change your converter into an `IMulitValueConverter`.

From your specific scenario (the converter tied to a ViewModel class, and a few of its properties), I would lean towards implementing the logic in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you don't show the full implementation. But I think it should update, if the value bound to the GUI provides the PropertyChanged-Event.

Regards

Comment: The problem is that the image source is bound directly to the datacontext, not a property of the datacontext. The converter takes in the datacontext and returns an image source.  

To clarify, the update occurs (works) if I use a binding that has a path to a property of the datacontext, and then call PropertyChanged for that property.  However, I need the object itself to determine the image (more than just a property).

Thanks.

Comment: had a thought while typing that out. I'm going to try to put a property on my object called "Self" which just returns itself, and then call PropertyChanged("Self"). I'll give this a shot.